# Cannot instantiate Object dynamically in PHP - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, object

So I am trying to dynamically instantiate an object in PHP with the specified string. However, Laravel says that the class could not be found.

I have been looking for a solution, but mostly have been told to make sure the namespace is correct. I had looked and I am sure they are correct (or my eyes are lying to me).

Here are my PHP files.

**OAuthController.php:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Interfaces\OAuthProvider;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Providers\GoogleProvider;
use App\Providers\FacebookProvider;
use App\Providers\AppleProvider;



class OAuthController extends Controller
{
    function redirectToProvider(Request $request){
        $validOauth = ['google','facebook','apple'];
        $provider = strtolower($request->provider);

        if (!in_array($provider, $validOauth)) {
            return redirect()->back(); 
        }
        
        // Call the provider object
        $providerObject = ucfirst($provider) . 'Provider';
        $providerInstance = new $providerObject;
        return $providerInstance->redirect();
    }

    function handleProviderCallback(Request $request){
        //
    }
}
```

**OAuthProvider.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Interfaces;
interface OAuthProvider{
    
    public function redirect();
    public function callback();
}
```

**GoogleProvider.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Providers;

use App\Interfaces\OAuthProvider;
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;

class GoogleProvider implements OAuthProvider
{
    public function redirect()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
    }

    public function callback()
    {
        // implementation for callback
    }
}
```

**Error:**
*Class "GoogleProvider" not found* // For every Provider

Comment: The advice to specify a namespace was correct - the key is to understand that `use` statements are *not* considered when using a dynamic class name, so the namespace needs to be included *in the string you pass to the `new` operator*.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but when instantiating the Object and not before that (in the string).